# Xubuntu 15.04 hangs on suspend

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, suspend

I've done a new, fresh installation of Xubuntu 15.04 on an Acer Aspire E 11 (E3-112-C8R5). When I try to suspend (either by pressing the "suspend" button from the GUI, or closing the lid), the OS just freezes. The only way to make it work again is to turn the PC off by pressing the "power" button for several seconds.

The OS is fully updated to the-latest-and-greatest and the only additional software I've installed is Google Chrome browser and VLC media player.

There is no additional hardware attached (e.g. USB drives, USB mouses or anything else.)

Light Locker (known to cause problems with suspend for quite some time now) is turned off.

I've searched the internet, but I've only found issues with Xubuntu and suspend *on resume*.

*Hos should I proceed?*

Comment: did you find a fix for this issue ? I am having the same